# Laravel update records with ajax get TokenMismatchException error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to update records with simply ajax code such as :

```
$('[id^="change_user_status_account-"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ URL::route('changeUserStatusAccount') }}",
        data: {user_id: id[1]},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $("#change_user_status_account-1").text('Enable Account');
            } else {
                $("#change_user_status_account-1").text('Disable Account');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

`var id` in this ajax is `2` and dont have problem

but i get error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

Firebug error:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/epay-pro/public/changeUserStatusAccount"
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('/changeUserStatusAccount', array(
    'as' => 'changeUserStatusAccount', function () {
            $info = \App\User::find(Request::input('user_id'));
            $status = $info->status == 1 ? 0 : 1;
            $info->status = $status;
            $info->save();
            return $status;
    }
));
```

My Html:

```
<span id="change_user_status_account-{{$contents->id}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel has enabled the CSRF protection for the `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` request.

Hence, you should pass the [`X-CSRF-TOKEN`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token) header to the ajax request.

To [exclude a URI from the CSRF protection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris), you should add it to the `$except` property of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

Comment: `csrf` is only for `<form>` and i dont have any form for using ajax, thats is only simple link to click and using ajax for update record,

Comment: By default, Laravel has enabled the CSRF protection for the `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` request.

Comment: how to disable that for simple request for ajax? i dont need to have form for using route and update or delete records, my code work fine in laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
data: {user_id: id[1]},
```

to

```
data: {user_id: id[1], _token:{{ csrf_token() }}},
```

or add `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to your form.

Comment: post updated sir. i dont have any input for this ajax request